# how to inject iframe with popup.html from content script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to inject popup.html to web content. Below is my think

```
... page content

<div> <--! injected content !-->
   <iframe src="chrome-extension:/21jk32j11k3kj11/popup.html">
   </iframe>
</div>
```

Is it possible to show popup.html in web content?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's possible. When [manifest version](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifestVersion.html) 2 is active (introduced in Chrome 18, required in Chrome 23), you have to include the page in the [`"web_accessible_resources"` section of the manifest file](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#web_accessible_resources) though:

```
{ ...
    "web_accessible_resources": ["popup.html"],
  ...
}
```

The frame itself can be injected via a [Content script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html), see the documentation for usage and examples:

```
// Within a content script:
var f = document.createElement('iframe');
f.src = chrome.extension.getURL('popup.html');
document.body.appendChild(f); // Append to body, for example.
```

[`chrome.extension.getURL`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getURL) returns the absolute URL of `popup.html`, eg `chrome-extension://...32 letters.../popup.html`.