# Show video from chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia in a tab?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, video-streaming, screensharing

I am trying out `chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia` in a chrome extension and I can get a desktop stream just fine.

I am using the following to turn the stream into an `blob:`-URL in the background script as follows:

```
var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
```

What I can't seem to work out is how to set this as the src attribute of a video element on the injected page.

I have tried the following, each of which do not work:

### In Background.js:

```
var video     = document.getElementById("video");
var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
video.src     = objectUrl;
```

### In Content.js

```
//objectUrl is a string received in a message from the background page by the content page
var video     = document.getElementById("video");
video.src     = objectUrl;
```

I get the following in the javascript console:

> Not allowed to load local resource: blob:chrome-extension://panahgiakgfjeioddhenaabbacfmkclm/48ff3e53-ff6a-4bee-a1dd-1b8844591a91

I also get the same if I post the URL in a message all the way to the injected page.  Should this work? I'd really appreciate any advice here.

In my manifest I also have
`"web_accessible_resources": [ "*" ]` but that was only to see if it resolved this issue (it did not).

Comment: Hi, I tried this chrome.desktopCapture and while using **tab** as a DesktopCaptureSourceType, the chrome browser throws an error like

Answer (score 5):

In a content script, the DOM is shared with the page, so any DOM operations (such as setting the video `src`) is subject to the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) of the page, not the extension.

If you want to show the content of a tab, then you MUST pass a [`tab.Tab`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab) object to [`chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture#method-chooseDesktopMedia). This object can be obtained in many ways, including the [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) and [tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) APIs. Here is an example using the [extension button](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction):

background.js

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    // NOTE: If you want to use the media stream in an iframe on an origin
    // different from the top-level frame (e.g. http://example.com), set
    //  tab.url = 'http://example.com'; before calling chooseDesktopMedia!
    //  (setting tab.url only works in Chrome 40+)
    chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia([
        'screen', 'window'//, 'tab'
    ], tab, function(streamId) {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            alert('Failed to get desktop media: ' +
                chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
            return;
        }   

        // I am using inline code just to have a self-contained example.
        // You can put the following code in a separate file and pass
        // the stream ID to the extension via message passing if wanted.
        var code = '(' + function(streamId) {
            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({
                audio: false,
                video: {
                    mandatory: {
                        chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
                        chromeMediaSourceId: streamId
                    }   
                }   
            }, function onSuccess(stream) {
                var url = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                var vid = document.createElement('video');
                vid.src = url;
                document.body.appendChild(vid);
            }, function onError() {
                alert('Failed to get user media.');
            }); 
        } + ')(' + JSON.stringify(streamId) + ')';

        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
            code: code
        }, function() {
            if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                alert('Failed to execute script: ' +
                    chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
            }   
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

manifest.json

```js
{
    "name": "desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia for a tab",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Show desktop capture request"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "desktopCapture",
        "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. Unfortunately Google have decided to remove desktop capture from getUserMedia directly in the page, and now requires a Chrome extension.  Presumably the content script does the injection of the frame into the DOM, and it is then possible to set the src of the video element using the 2 lines of javascript I showed in the "In content.js" section of my first question?  To check, is this "frame" an iframe? Will calling document.getElementById from the content script automatically search the iframe too? Sorry, not that used to extensions yet. Thanks again, Simon.

Comment: @user1710407 The iframe will be a part of the web page, and it is still affected by the usual same origin policy. You have to use the [extension message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) API to securely exchange information from the background page with the extension page in the iframe (the object URL). And obviously this iframe page must be listed in [`web_accessible_resources`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources).

Comment: Your answer on http://stackoverflow.com/q/11527266/1710407 shows how to inject the iframe, but it is setting the src on the video element within the injected frame that I'm not sure how to do here.

Comment: Hi Rob. When I set the .src property of the video element in the injected frame, I see a 404 not found in the console. e.g. `GET blob:chrome-extension://fshihgiakgfjeioddhenaabbacfmkace/bce395d1-f442-4502-8b62-69f63b8f4c28 404 (Not Found)`   
In my background script I do: 
`URL.createObjectURL(stream);`
then send this using port.postMessage to the injected iframe as a string and set the src of the video element in the injected.html page to that url.  This should work right as they're in the same origin?  Unescaping the URL seems to make no difference.

Comment: @user1710407 Have you already tried to pass a `tab.Tab` object type to [`chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture#method-chooseDesktopMedia)? This object is available as the second parameter of [`chrome.runtime.onMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage) (`sender.tab`), and can also be obtained through [`chrome.tabs.query`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query).

Comment: I don't understand - why do I need this?

Comment: To make the stream available in that tab. Read the documentation.

Comment: @user1710407 I have added a complete example to the answer.

Comment: @RobW I'm using the example - it pops open the `chooseDesktopMedia` but as soon as I click on on a stream I'm getting `Failed to get user media.`. Any leads you can give me as to what might be at fault? Do I need to have a video element already on my page?

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides What's the exact error message that you're getting? Have you already read and followed the instructions in the code, right before the `chooseDesktopMedia` invocation?

Comment: I'm inspecting the console of the background-page and no error appears other than the `onError()` alert message you put there. Yep I did setting `tab.url` to the current page I'm triggering the extension on. Thanks a lot for answering

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides Can't reproduce. Can you share the source code and/or a video of the issue?

Comment: Sent to your mail - We can paste solution here if it comes to that:)

Comment: @RobW Was working after all, sorry. Just needs SSL, like you told me.

Comment: Hi, I tried this chrome.desktopCapture and while using **tab** as a DesktopCaptureSourceType, the chrome browser throws an error like `desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia: Tab capture is not supported yet` . Could anyone suggest me a solution

Comment: @muthu Use the [`chrome.tabCapture`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabCapture) API

Comment: @RobW How to stop Recording a tab via chrome.tabCapture API, which is already being recorded via the same API? I stopped StreamRecording but that doesn't help. Can anyone have a example extension that uses chrome.tabCapture API

Comment: @muthu I see that you've created a separate question, please keep the questions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34656673/chrome-desktopcapture-throws-an-error-on-tab-as-desktopcapturesourcetype. Have you tried calling `.stop()` on all media tracks of the MediaStream that you got via `getUserMedia` (`webkitGetUserMedia`)?

Answer (score 0):

ObjectURLs can't be shared cross-origin. A Data URL can be shared cross-origin if it works with your video stream (I'm not sure).