# chrome.desktopCapture throws an error on "tab" as DesktopCaptureSourceType

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, recording

I am developing a chrome extension, and my point here is to record a browser tab , like [Screencastify](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screencastify-screen-vide/mmeijimgabbpbgpdklnllpncmdofkcpn?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) chrome extension records the browser tab. I referred [desktopCapture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture) , a chrome API which works perfectly for "screen" and "window" as DesktopCaptureSourceType, whereas for "tab" as DesktopCaptureSourceType, it throws an error as

> desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia: Tab capture is not supported yet.

I have configured the required permissions in manifest.json of my extension. Could anyone suggest me a solution?

P.S : I need to record the chrome browser tab only, am not asking for a screen or window recording

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue: https://crbug.com/488262

However, you can use the [chrome.tabCapture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabCapture) api instead. The downside is that you will have to split your interface between capturing tabs and screens/windows, as chrome.tabCapture doesn't provide an equivalent picker.

Why does Google have two separate screen capture apis? Good question.

Comment: How to stop Recording a tab via chrome.tabCapture API, which is already being recorded via the same API

Comment: Have you tried reading this? (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/12/Screensharing-with-WebRTC?hl=en) Official Chrome documentation: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabCapture

Comment: @d.datul1990 That doesn't help, chrome.tabCapture API runs at the background even after the streamRecording is stoped. Can anyone have a example for this chrome.tabcapture API

Comment: I got the stream through chrome.tabCapture API and I need to record that stream and save it in server. Can anyone help with that? It would be better if I get a code snippet. Also, how to end this chrome.tabCapture API to stop capturing the tab

Answer (score 0):

The stream object generated by the chrome.tabCapture cant be shared outside the plugin code.

You will have to write the code to share the stream to server within the chrome plugin.